# how to set commands for mvn in bash in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, maven, command, environment-variables

when I just type `gre` in my command-line, press `tab` it autofills the command `grep` in my bash.

similarly when I type, `gi` in my commandline and press `tab`, it autofills `git command.

how does this work? I want to do similar for `maven`, which I have installed it.

The `terminal` I used to install `maven`, works with the `tab`. but with any new `terminal` opened, it does not work. In fact, with new `Terminals` when I type the `mvn`, I `get command not found`. 
some little explanation and how to fix this will be very helpful.

If it is possible to briefly explain `environment variables` and `.bashrc`, it will be good to know.
I did searching but I am getting confused

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making it work across all bash sessions, you have to edit `.bash_profile`. 
Follow this post [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028872/mvn-command-not-found-in-osx-mavrerick/21030998#21030998) to see if that helps.

Regarding auto-completion, you could try what `khmarbaise` suggested above or [this one.](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-bash-m2-completion.html)
I suppose the it is for `mvn 2.X versions`, I don't know if it works for `mvn 3.1 versions`

Answer (score 1):

It look like you are searching for a [maven-bash-completion](https://github.com/juven/maven-bash-completion).